# Radiobutton not working (simple code)

Tags: java, android, radio-button

Well, the issue is... my code is supposed to output the amount from the radiobutton clicked by the user, but it's not outputting the amount at all... I'm really not sure what the problem is. I created a radiogroup and used if-statements to determine if a radiobutton was checked or not. I think the issue is somewhere in calculating the amount.
Do I need to make a button? I thought it would calculate the amount automatically with the if-statements when a radiobutton were clicked. If I need a button, how would I go about creating one? (I'm trying to avoid using listener for now)

I'm a complete noob at android/java. I really would appreciate it if someone could explain what's wrong with my code. Thanks!

**JAVA CODE**
    package com.Rox.crazyjoe;

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final double smallcst = 1.25;
        final double mediumcst = 2.00;
    final double largecst = 3.50;
    double amount;


    RadioButton small = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioSmall);
    RadioButton medium = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioMedium);
    RadioButton large = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioLarge);


    if (small.isChecked())
    {
        amount = smallcst;
    }
    else if(large.isChecked())
    {
        amount = largecst;
    }
    else if(medium.isChecked())
    {
        amount = mediumcst;
    }
        else
    {
        amount = 0;
    }

            DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$##.00");

    TextView t0 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textAmount);
    t0.setText("Total Amount: " + money.format(amount));

        }

       }
```

**XML CODE:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Size: "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

  <RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Small" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:text="Medium" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/radioMedium"
        android:layout_below="@+id/radioMedium"
        android:text="Large" />


  </RadioGroup>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textAmount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
    android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You will need an event to check those radio buttons. You could use a button click, or attach a listener to the RadioGroup. (Check answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need an event to trigger the checking of the radio buttons. At the moment, it is just checking the if statement in the onCreate and that's it (if you had a radiobutton checked by default, a value would be set here). I recommend attaching a listener to the entire RadioGroup

```
radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);
            //other logic here (like what do you want to do with this selected RadioButton)
        }
});
```